# Extract value out of another value (possibly using RegEx)

Tags: c#, regex

What I am looking for is a way to extract the URL out of an href attribute.  I care about all parameters EXCEPT the sessionToken parameters.

So this…

```
<A class=ContentURL href="javascript:void(window.open('../content/ModuleList.aspx?PageID=module&amp;sessionToken=[sessionToken]','report','scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=640,height=500'))">Manage Applications</A>
```

Should give me this…

```
../content/ModuleList.aspx?PageID=module
```

And this…

```
<A class=ContentURL href="javascript:void(window.open('../content/ModuleList.aspx?PageID=module&amp;sessionToken=[sessionToken]&amp;Token=DateTime','report','scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=640,height=500'))">Manage Applications</A>
```

Should give me this…

```
../content/ModuleList.aspx?PageID=module&amp;Token=DateTime
```

I have to imagine there is a way to do this using RegEx and I was hoping someone could show me how.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#". We use tags for that on [SO].

Answer (score 1):

If all of your links have the same format you specified, then pattern for extracting URLs is simple:

```
href="javascript:void\(window\.open\('(.+?)'.*?"
```

URL will be captured by the first group: `(.+?)`.

Now having extracted URLs, you can do anything you want with them. If you want to remove sessionToken parameter without breaking GET string (by accidently removing `?` or `&` character), you should replace `(\??)sessionToken=[^&]*&?` with 1st capturing group (a `?` if  sessionToken is a first parameter and an empty string if it's not). You might also want to remove trailing `&` if sessionToken is a last parameter, but that's not necessarily.